# How can I apply watchify to my gulp file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp

I want to use gulp on my nodeJS to pack React.

This is my gulpfile:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
let browserify = require('browserify');
let babelify = require('babelify');
let source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
let buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');


gulp.task('js',()=>{
    return browserify({
        entries : ['./App/app.js'],
        extensive : ['.js'],
        debug:true
    })
        .transform(babelify,babelify.configure())
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
});

gulp.task('default',['js']);
```

I try to use Watchify to accelerate the packing speed, because the packing speed is little slow when the project becomes big.

Then I try to use Watchify to accelerate the rate. Unfortunately, the speed even lower.

How can I use Watchify properly, or how can I improve my gulp file.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean a watch task? If so you can add a watch task to keep an eye on anything that changes and run other (specified) tasks when they do.

```
gulp.task ('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(app.css, ['css']);
    gulp.watch(app.js, ['js']);

});
// default task 
gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css', 'watch']);
```

this will watch your css, js files for any changes.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, would this watch task accelerate my packaging process.

Comment: The watch task will compile only changes, thus your project build time will speed up. There is more info here [fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md)

Comment: Thank you very much